# How should I connect electrical wires to a cooktop (platetop)?

Tags: electrical, appliances

I'm having some problems understanding how to connect some electric wires for a platetop.

[image: http://www.ikea.com/no/no/images/products/framtid-hgct-glasskeramisk-topp__0094520_PE232383_S4.JPG]

The wire colors normally mean, blue=N, brown=L, and yellow/green=PE.

[image]

My problem is, the platetop has L1 & L2:

[image]

When I connect the blue wire to L1, nothing happens. When I connect the blue wire to L2, then the platetop works, but only half of them on the right.

This is how it's connected now:

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: if you only have one phase wiring (phase + neutral) you need to strap both phase inputs L1 and L2 together, as is indicated in the wiring diagram you posted in the "230V" example. if you connect it as you did, only half of the heaters will be connected probably. also, it is better to pull two phases and neutral to the top though as is indicated in the 400V diagram but you should really get an electrician if you can't get this correct - you'll burn up your house if you connect a 7200W induction top through wiring not intended for this power at a single phase for example.

Comment: Location?  It looks like you are somewhere in Europe?

Answer (score 9):

### THIS IS NOT A JOKE- THIS APPLIANCE NEEDS TO BE INSTALLED PROPERLY

This is how it should be wired using 220-240volt

[image]

**BUT**

There are some things to consider first!

The wires you are using to connect to .. are they the provided wires? there should have been a solid copper U bridge to connect L1/L2 to each other too!? Where is it?

If that is not the original cable you must consider using 2.5mm solid core cable

[image]

But also the wire that is in the plug should be the same/similar type! and it should be **DEDICATED ONLY**
meaning no other plugs on that line

Before the stove you need an isolation switch (any electrician that says this is not needed is a bad electrician!)

[image]

And **MOST IMPORTANT**

### **A 8AMP (MAX 1700WATT) on 2.5MM Solid Core Dedicated Line!!!**

[image]

Be warned if you do not meet these requirements you are putting your self at a electrical fire risk - and this is for ALL 220VOLT Installation anywhere in the world. If you have ome insurance and it burns down and they find that your new stove did not meet these electrical rules.. sorry - insurance void!!  Even after installation you need a NEW electrical test certificate to certify there are no GROUND leaks! or micro shorts!

Comment: Where on earth are you getting 8A from? 2.5mm^2 is generally considered good for 16A in all conditions down under, and can be 20-25A if well cooled (however, this stove likely requires 32A). Plus, flexible cable (not solid core) is absolutely an acceptable solution in this case.

Comment: Most of what I have quoted is what the electronics regulations required in South Africa. Alternatives are fine as long as you know what you doing. The 8AMP thing came from a comment- the OP was asking if 8 AMP was. I explained how much 8 AMP can handle. Probably not clear now- Yea16A is preffered

Comment: Why does it need to be a solid wire? I've just connected an similar hob with a 2.5mm^2 stranded wire (this is required by its spec sheet). What could go wrong?

Comment: @sydd  This is also quite the norm from what I have seen in many places of the world for hard wired stuff to be solid core and not stranded. You should not have a problem really if it does not exceed the ~1700Watts on 8A @ 220V - Stranded is used in appliances mostly because its cheaper to make

Answer (score 3):

I've just installed an electric Zanussi Ceramic Hob (under supervision from a qualified electrician), and the image of your wiring box looks exactly the same as mine. What the person above says (ppumkin) is absolutely right. The copper U bridge was needed in mine, and I think you do have one as I can see the a very tiny bit of it in your picture (where mine was too). Mine was tucked away underneath as my picture below shows.
[image: Image showing where the bridge was supplied.]

Before I tightened the screws for L1 and L2, I just tucked the 'bridge' under the **L1** and **L2** screws and then tightened them.

Ensure your wires are suitable for the current that will pass.

Answer (score 2):

No instructions came with our Zanussi hob. We were unable to locate the bridge until we looked online. If you do not use the bridge you will get an E36 error code, as you have not activated the second phase.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Thanks for the answer; keep 'em coming. And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know the details of contributing here.

Answer (score -2):

Why blue on L2? WRONG !! Use 4 wires, 2 phases, neutral(blue) and ground(yellow). Dont use 1 phase if your house have 3 phases. Every kitchen have to had a 3 phase. Connect like this:

[image: L3 is empty]