# How do I connect 4 electrical wires to a 3-phase cooktop?

Tags: electrical, kitchens

I need to connect the wires to my new IKEA cooktop. I learned from the website  that the wire colors normally mean, blue=N, brown=L, and yellow/green=PE.

However, I have a (3-phase) cable with 4 colored wires: white, brown, blue and yellow/green.

Should I connect the the brown wire to L2 (2), white wire to L1 (1), if there are 5 connecting points, from top to bottom are 1, 2, 3(no connecting screw), N, and PE.

From denmark

Comment: post a link and we'll paste it in for you till you get more reputation

Comment: Are you in Europe or North America?

Comment: I think you mean its 240V, not 3-phase?

Comment: Possible Duplicate: [How should I connect electrical wires to a cooktop platetop](http://diy.stackexchange.com/q/7637/33)

Comment: It sounds like there are two of the three phases available, not the two legs of 120 V like things are done in the USA. That is nearly a duplicate, and this question probably could be merged with that one, but in this question, the two phases available, while in that one, only one phase available.

Answer (score 2):

Since you are in Denmark, your mains are 400 V phase-phase, and 230 V phase to neutral. The white and brown wires are two of the three phases, and the yellow/green is your ground. You don't have a wire for the third phase available.

The standard IEC color code says that blue is neutral, brown is L1, grey (what you call white) is L3.

Your stove, since it doesn't have the screw for L3, presumably only needs two phases of power, neutral, and ground. This is what you have available.

You should connect yellow/green to PE and blue to N. I'd connect grey to (1) and brown to (2), preserving the ordering of the phases. The configuration of these two "hot" wires likely does not matter, as the cooktop's loads are likely all connected phase->neutral instead of phase->phase.