# Hi i have had my stove isolator moved but having some problem now. the circuit breaker stays up for a while then trips

Tags: circuit-breaker

Hi i have had my stove isolator moved but having some problem now. the circuit breaker stays up for a while then trips, but the stranger thing is that my breaker trips even with nothing on. what can the problem be?

Comment: What do you mean by "stove isolator", a dedicated switch for the stove circuit? Where on this planet are you anyhow?

Comment: @Three: I assumed Dominic meant something like the one in [this answer](https://diy.stackexchange.com/a/7642/2815) but, as you say, location is important for this type of question.

Answer (score 1):

> **[I did X and bad things happened - what can be the cause of the bad things?]**

X!

> **[and what should I do about it?]**

I'd check that stove isolator very carefully, particularly the wiring, which wires connect where, the quality of all connections in its vicinity, the amount of room in the box, the possibility of exposed metal or wires coming into contact with each other as the box cover is closed and the quality of any reused or replacement parts.

If you paid someone to move the isolator, that person/business should be fixing your problem for free.